# Why are attributes missing in overlay tab QGIS 1.8.0?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, overlay, diagram

I want to add a diagram overlay onto a shapefile layer. When I look at the attribute table, all the correct columns are shown. However, when I open the layer property box, the attribute columns I want to display are not available in the drop down list. Would this be because there are some NULL values in the attribute table? How do I get around it?

Answer (score 2):

It's more likely that those attributes are not numeric but strings. You can use field calculator to create new, numeric attributes from the strings if necessary.